# In force.com IDE / eclipse: Is it possible to see a temporarily created destructiveChanges.xml when I delete metadata?

Tags: metadata-api, eclipse, force.com-ide, destructivechanges.xml

I use eclipse for deletions of layouts. Clicking through the UI it works just fine. But I have to do it over an over again on many orgs and now I want to automate that task with ant.

Maybe I'm wrong but I would assume, that eclipse might generate a temporary destructiveChanges.xml. If so, is there a way to find it in my filesystem? (Windows)

If not, is there any other way to use an UI to create an destructiveChanges.xml?

Answer (score 1):

The destructiveChanges.xml file follows the exact same format as the package.xml file format. I'm mobile right now, but it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"> 
  <types>
    <members>Account-Account Layout</members>
    <name>Layout</name> 
  </types>
  <version>41.0</version> 
</Package>
```

Simply list each layout, object name then layout name, separated by a hyphen.

Technically, in the Force.com IDE, if you select the layouts in the project, then select Save to server, your package.xml should already be in the correct format for you to copy-paste into a destructiveChanges.xml file for an Ant script directory or DX directory.